Low resolution problem after installing driver Nvidia on Opensuse Leap 15.6
I installed opensuse leap 15.6 and after installing the NVIDIA drivers, at the reboot it loaded but with a low resolution, making it impossible to set it to a higher one even through system settings, there was no other higher resolution available.
could someone give me some advice on this, perhaps explaining in detail the steps or commands that I can do to solve the problem?
my gpu is GE FORCE 1050 Ti (rev a1) driver gp107 .
thanks

If you run lsmod | grep nvidia, what is the output? If there is no output from that command, them the NVIDIA kernel modules are not loaded: either there was a problem in building a kernel module matching your current kernel; or you have received a kernel update after installing the driver and you don't have DKMS or some other mechanism that would auto-rebuild the NVIDIA modules for any updated kernels for you.

Also, did you use SuSE-specific procedure or did you download the generic installation package from nvidia.com?

I used the SUSE Specific procedure  from yast and this time everithing seems to work.  Thank you very much telcoM
